# Issue with declaring multiline functions in APL

Tags: scripting, apl, dyalog

```
#!/usr/bin/dyalog -script
⍝ /usr/bin/dyalog is a symlink to /opt/mdyalog/18.0/64/unicode/mapl

factors←{⎕ML ⎕IO←1 ⋄  ⍵{ ⍵,(⍺÷×/⍵)~1}∊⍵{(0=(⍵*⍳⌊⍵⍟⍺)|⍺)/⍵}¨⍬{nxt←⊃⍵ ⋄ msk←0≠nxt|⍵ ⋄ ∧/1↓msk:⍺,⍵ ⋄ (⍺,nxt)∇ msk/⍵}⍵{ (0=⍵|⍺)/⍵}2,(1+2×⍳⌊0.5×⍵*÷2),⍵}
factors 20
```

Copied from https://dfns.dyalog.com/c_factors.htm
It works exactly as the example apart from the fact I am not able to to type it as separate lines and have to resort to `⋄`'s

Using the example it instead results in

```
./.local/src/sandbox/apl/Main.apl                                                                                                                                                                                                     
SYNTAX ERROR
 factors←{⎕ML ⎕IO←1          ⍝ Prime factors of ⍵.
```

Another issue is using `]` commands like `]display` or `]box on`
Using them always results in

```
./.local/src/sandbox/apl/Main.apl                                                                                                                                                                                                     

VALUE ERROR: Undefined name: ⎕SE.UCMD
```

Answer (score 5):

Try* adding setting [DYALOG_LINEEDITOR_MODE](https://help.dyalog.com/latest/#UserGuide/Installation%20and%20Configuration/Configuration%20Parameters/Dyalog_LineEditor_Mode.htm) to 1:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/dyalog -script DYALOG_LINEEDITOR_MODE=1
```

When running in script mode, SALT, and therefore user commands, are not initialised automatically. As [per APLcart](https://aplcart.info?q=enable%20salt), you can enable both with:

```
(⎕NS⍬).(_←enableSALT⊣⎕CY'salt')
```

However, under program control, you're usually better off using proper functions than user commands. You can copy in the `display` and `disp` functions (which take an array and produce character matrices equivalent to what you'd see from `]display` and `]box on`) with:

```
'display' 'disp'⎕CY'dfns'
```

---

* Both `-script` and `DYALOG_LINEEDITOR_MODE` are experimental in version 18.0, while 18.2 (scheduled for release in March 2022) has dedicated #! script support.

Comment: Oh thanks, though what is the non experimental way of running apl script files?

Comment: @Perigord There is none in 18.0, as version 18.2 is the first version with actual support for script files.

Comment: @Adám Hi Adam, `#!/usr/bin/dyalog -script DYALOG_LINEEDITOR_MODE=1` I was trying to add this but my `bin` does not have a `dyalog` folder or file so I get an error. I have a Dyalog file in `Library/Application Support` but that didn't recognize the `-script` command. (v.18.2) Mac Osx. Is there another way? This page https://mastering.dyalog.com/User-Defined-Functions.html#fig-ride-enable-multiline-input recommends adding it as Environment Variable in RIDE, but I could not find where. Thanks